# Latex not rendering in Opera

Tags: support, status-completed

For some reason LaTeX is not working properly in my browser. I can see everything that is done in display mode, but anything that is between dollar signs does not parse at all. I've tried restarting and refreshing several times. Firefox seems to work perfectly fine. Anyone else have this problem and any idea how to fix it? Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem (Firefox 3.0.6 and 3.6.15 on Linux and Windows, but Chrome works fine). Reloading the page seems to help, so it may be some kind of script loading race.

Comment: I have the same problem on Opera 11.52 running on Mac OS X 10.7.2. It happens whenever I am logged-in, and not logged-in, but that is kind of expected.

Comment: A fix will be deployed tonight.

Comment: @JarrodDixon, you have readers in timezones all around the world. Your tonight is probably not my tonight. Perhaps in the future you could write "tonight, New York time" or "tonight, Johannesburg time" or "tonight, Tokyo time" or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sure, will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The math.stackexchange.com site recently has put the MathJax configuration block in the wrong location, and that produces a timing dependency that causes some people not to get the configuration changes that enable the dollar-sign math delimiters.  Looks like Opera is one of the browsers that is affected by this.

See the [MathJax documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/configuration.html#using-in-line-configuration-options) for details about where to place the MathJax configuration block.

Comment: + 1 This was exactly the issue - thanks!